# How to give selectYear in pickadate function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, pickadate

Hi I am using pickdate and I am having field this in my view :

```
<%= f.text_field :date_of_birth,:placeholder =>'Select Date',
                     :class => 'datepicker picker_input' %>
```

So in this I have this jquery

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            selectMonths: true,
            selectYears: 60
    });
```

So it gives me years from 1985 to 2045 but I want years from 1945 to current_year. How to fetch this with the help of pickadate. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a function that calculates the amount of years between 1945 and now and then assign it to your pickadate

Comment: Can you show us what did you tried ?

Comment: Ya its given in my question only

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting the `max` option to `true`

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  selectMonths: true,
  selectYears: 60,
  max: true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            selectMonths: true,
            selectYears: 70,
            max: true
    });
```

Comment: If you just set max true option and won't change selectYears value then it will display years from 1955 and you can check this

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  selectMonths: true,
  min: new Date(1945,1,1),
  max: true
});
```

try using `min` so you would have more control over the minimum year range you wanted without worrying if the selectYear still reaches the current year

Comment: Could you update your answer and explain what you are doing. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '1945:'+(new Date).getFullYear()         
    });
});
```